# Bar Chart. How to add colour to font label values?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, label, bar-chart

From MS Access, I need to add a red colour and bold to font label values in my `xlBarStacked` Chart in Excel Worksheet.

I have already googled here and other VBA pages and have not found any similar example.

This code adds values (font black) to labels (I need red colour):

```
Sub chartlabelvaluecolor_()
    .
    .
    Set xlChart = ws.ChartObjects(1)
        With xlChart
            With .chart
                    .SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowLabel
            End with
        End with
    .
    .
End Sub
```

Did anybody manage to pull off an example like this before?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I just searched for "ms access vba set font color" and https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=34499 is the very first result. Does that not work? If not, can you show what you've tried already, based on answers you've found on the internet? (it seems highly unlikely you're the first person in history to try to change the color of some text, I'm willing to be the answer to this can already be easily found with targeted searching)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans. Thank you for your reply.
I read the link you indicate, but, the code's syntax is not clear to my VBA level. Therefore, I couldn't adapt it to my char bar labels code.

For example, after the last line of my code:
1. I couldn't write an If
2. The use of [control].ForeColor is not indicated by VBA Editor Intellisense

The remaining instructions are beyond my current VBA knowledge.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: This is more "general understanding of how people give answers" than VBA: in that thread, the person explaining how to do things uses `[control]` as a placeholder for the thing that the colors are getting changed for.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans. 
Many thanks for considering my request.
I apologize. Your replies are beyond my VBA knowledge.
I know, I have to study more about Charts in VBA.
Cheers